# Plot ROC curve for Nearest Centroid

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scikit-learn

I want to plot a ROC curve for evaluating a trained Nearest Centroid classifier.
My code works for Naive Bayes, SVM, kNN and DT but I get an exception whenever I try to plot the curve for Nearest Centroid, because the estimator has no `.predict_proba()` method:

```
AttributeError: 'NearestCentroid' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'
```

The code for plotting the curve is

```
def plot_roc(self):
    plt.clf()
        
    for label, estimator in self.roc_estimators.items():
        estimator.fit(self.data_train, self.target_train)
        proba_for_each_class = estimator.predict_proba(self.data_test)

        fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(self.target_test, proba_for_each_class[:, 1])

        plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label=label)

    plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], linestyle='--', lw=2, color='r', label='Luck', alpha=.8)

    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

`self.roc_estimators` is a dict where I store the trained estimators with the label of the classifier like this

```
cl_label = "kNN"
knn_estimator = KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='ball_tree', p=2, n_neighbors=5)
knn_estimator.fit(self.data_train, self.target_train)
self.roc_estimators[cl_label] = knn_estimator
```

and for Nearest Centroid respectively

```
cl_label = "Nearest Centroid"
nc_estimator = NearestCentroid(metric='euclidean', shrink_threshold=6)
nc_estimator.fit(self.data_train, self.target_train)
self.roc_estimators[cl_label] = nc_estimator
```

So it works for all classifiers I tried but not for Nearest Centroid. Is there a specific reason regarding the nature of the Nearest Centroid classifier that I am missing which explains why it is not possible to plot the ROC curve (more specifically why the estimator does not have the `.predict_proba()` method?) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a "score" for each prediction to make the ROC curve. This could be the predicted probability of belonging to one class.

See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Curves_in_ROC_space

Just looking for the nearest centroid will give you predicted class, but not the probability.

EDIT: For NearestCentroid it is not possible to compute a score. This is simply a limitation of the model. It assigns a class to each sample, but not a probability of that class. I guess if you need to use Nearest Centroid and you want a probability, you can use some ensemble method. Train a bunch of models of subsets of your training data, and average their predictions on your test set. That could give you a score. See scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#bagging

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although my `proba_for_each_class[:, 1]` is the score you suggest, I guess? The problem is not the plot of the roc corve itself, maybe that was a misleading phrase. I am not able to compute this score for Nearest Centroid.

Comment: Yes, for `NearestCentroid` it is not possible to compute a score. This is simply a limitation of the model. It assigns a class to each sample, but not a probability of that class.

I guess if you need to use Nearest Centroid and you want a probability, you can use some ensemble method. Train a bunch of models of subsets of your training data, and average their predictions on your test set. That could give you a score. See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#bagging

Comment: Alright, thank you! You may insert your comment in your answer and I accept it.

Comment: @ncw NearestCentroid assign classes based on the minimum distance. You can get the distances from all classes and then convert them to some kind of probability.

Comment: @ncw Sure, I added the comment to my answer

Answer (score 0):

To get the class probabilities you can do something like (untested code):

```
from sklearn.utils.extmath import softmax
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances

def predict_proba(self, X):
    distances = pairwise_distances(X, self.centroids_, metric=self.metric)
    probs = softmax(distances)
    return probs

clf = NearestCentroid()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
predict_proba(clf, X_test)
```